# Is there a css property that can differentiate between Android app left and right swiping and area horizontal scrolling?

Tags: html, css, scroll, frontend, ems

I sprinkled webpage content inside an Android native app with left and right swiping applied.

Among the elements inside the web page, there is an area that has a partial horizontal scroll with overflow-x:auto property.

However, when you try to scroll the horizontal scrollable area with a touch, the left and right swiping applied to the native app is executed and the page itself is moved.

(To be more precise, it's a situation where you check the contents of the mail in the Android Google Mail app.)

Is there a css property(As it is sent by email) that can prevent the swiping from being executed when trying to scroll the part with the overflow-x:auto property?

Comment: You'd be better designing around having to horizontally scroll as that behaviour is within the app it's being viewed in.

Comment: @learningtoanimate I wanted to expose the scroll in the email, but... After all, it seems that there is only that way.  Thank you for your answer :D